# Simulate data with correlations to multiple other vectors

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

I am trying to simulate a vector that is correlated to a few other vectors. I figured out the code for simulating a vector correlated to one other vector, but can't figure out how to simulate it with correlations to multiple other vectors:

Here is my code:

```
library(faux)
p4<-rnorm_pre(data$p1, mu = 0, sd = 10, r = 0.4, empirical = FALSE)
```

What I would like to do is somehow identify multiple vectors for the simulated trait to be correlated to. Im not sure if this library is the best to use

My data look like

```
 ID  p1  p2  p3 
 1 0.25 0.30 0.02
 2 0.05 0.67 0.18
 3 0.09 0.31 0.38
 4 0.55 0.87 0.21
 5 0.25 0.64 0.01
```

And I would like to add another column called p4 that is the vector of simulated data, which is correlated to p1 and p3.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: By *"correlations to multiple other parameters"* do you mean *"correlations to multiple other **vectors**"*?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data$p1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data$p1, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I have updated with sample data (the full dataset if very large). yes, I did mean a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new vector can be created just like the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/faux/vignettes/rnorm_multi.html) says.

```
library(faux)

data$p4 <- rnorm_pre(
  data[-1],             # remove 1st column ID
  mu = 0, 
  sd = 4, 
  r = c(-0.2, 0.2, 0.1)
)

cor(data[-1])
#           p1         p2          p3          p4
#p1  1.0000000  0.5695821 -0.20120754 -0.21833687
#p2  0.5695821  1.0000000 -0.08533300  0.60506386
#p3 -0.2012075 -0.0853330  1.00000000  0.06803646
#p4 -0.2183369  0.6050639  0.06803646  1.00000000
```

---

Here is a way to specify correlations with only columns `p1` and `p3`.

```
data$p5 <- rnorm_pre(
  data[c("p1", "p3")],  # only columns p1 and p3
  mu = 0,
  sd = 1,
  r = c(0.5, -0.2)
)

cor(data[c("p1", "p3", "p5")])
#           p1         p3         p5
#p1  1.0000000 -0.2012075  0.5772403
#p3 -0.2012075  1.0000000 -0.0806465
#p5  0.5772403 -0.0806465  1.0000000
```

### Data in `dput` format

```
data <-
structure(list(ID = 1:5, p1 = c(0.25, 0.05, 0.09, 0.55, 0.25), 
    p2 = c(0.3, 0.67, 0.31, 0.87, 0.64), p3 = c(0.02, 0.18, 0.38, 
    0.21, 0.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am only looking to simulate 1 vector (p4). The other vectors  are already there. When you created the data correlation matrix, it also created correlations between all the other p# vectors. for example, I want p4 to have a correlations of -0.3 with p1 and 0.2 with p3.   I don't think I understand the process of the code. @Rui Barradas

Comment: @Cae.rich Function `rnorm_pre` creates the new vector with the mean, sd and correlations given. These are population statistics, since `empirical = FALSE` by default. The data correlation matrix is only meant to see what are the actual correlation values of the vector `p4` that the function managed to generate with the other vectors.

Comment: @Cae.rich I asked for a `cor(p1, p4) == -0.2` and got `-0.21833687`, for instance. `cor(p2, p4)` is even very far from the wanted value passed as an argument to the function.

Comment: Got it! That makes sense. So the  r = c(-0.2, 0.2, 0.1)  states the desired correlation between p4 and p1, p2, and p3, respectively? is there a way to specific the correlation for only some of the vectors, not all of them. For example, p1 and p3, but have no correlation specific for p2? Thanks for all of your help

Comment: @Cae.rich You can specify the correlations for some of the vectors if you subset the data.frame, will edit with an example.

Comment: When I use the code, it keeps bringing up this code, " x must be a vector". Any thoughts?

Comment: @Cae.rich With the data as posted I cannot reproduce the error. Are you running the code on data with the same structure? You can try `as.matrix(data[-1])` or `as.matrix(data[c("p1", "p3")])` and see if it solves the problem.